# Android - How to check if a button background color is the same as the previous one in the view (programmatically)

Tags: android, list, button, colors

In my app, i add buttons programmatically to my view. I maked a LinkedList of String to put this : 
numers are colors

```
    ArrayList lesCouleurs;
```

I add the colors :

```
lesCouleurs = new ArrayList<>();
    lesCouleurs.add(0, Color.RED);
    lesCouleurs.add(1, Color.BLUE);
    lesCouleurs.add(2, Color.CYAN);
    lesCouleurs.add(3, Color.GREEN);
    lesCouleurs.add(4, Color.YELLOW);
    lesCouleurs.add(5, Color.WHITE);
```

Here is my method to add buttons programmatically :(Commentaries are in French)

```
 private void addButton() {
    //Instanciation de l'enteier aléatoire


    //Création programmatique d'un boutonn (cf. Doc Création programmatique de boutons)
    final Button button = new Button(this);
    //Instanciation du MediaPlayer
    final MediaPlayer[] mediaPlayer = {new MediaPlayer()};
    mediaPlayer[0].setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    //On récupère la taille de l'écran du terminal
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
    button.setWidth(metrics.widthPixels / 2);
    button.setHeight(metrics.heightPixels / 6);
    //Et on ajoute les boutons à la vue avec les paramètres ajoutés ci-dessus
    linearLayout.addView(button);

    String myString = nomFichier;
    int index = myString.indexOf(".");
    String fileNameForButton = myString.substring(0, index);
    button.setText(fileNameForButton);
    button.setTextSize(25);

    //On met le texte du bouton en gras
    button.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));


    //On choisit de manière aléatoire la couleur dans la liste proposée
    int random= 0;
    int color = 0;
    if (nbButton > 0) {
        while ((linearLayout.getChildAt(nbButton - 1).getBackground()).equals(linearLayout.getChildAt(nbButton).getBackground())) {
            random = new Random().nextInt(lesCouleurs.size());
            color = (int) lesCouleurs.get(random);
        }
        button.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
    else {
        random = new Random().nextInt(lesCouleurs.size());
        color = (int) lesCouleurs.get(random);
        button.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    final Uri myUri = Uri.parse(currentDir + "/" + nomFichier);
    button.setTag(R.id.tag_uri, myUri);

    //Dans le create, .prepare() est fait automatiquement pas besoin de le refaire dans le test if

    final MediaPlayer[] finalMediaPlayer = {mediaPlayer[0]};

    //Quand on clique sur le bouton
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (modeDelete) {
                //Si le mode delete est activé, on supprime le bouton de la vue
                linearLayout.removeView(button);
            } else {
                //En dehors du mode delete , on joue le son demandé
                finalMediaPlayer[0].stop();
                finalMediaPlayer[0].release();
                finalMediaPlayer[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
                finalMediaPlayer[0].setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
                finalMediaPlayer[0].start();
            }

        }
    });
    mediaPlayer[0].setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });

    nbButton ++;

    //On commit la nouvelle valeur dans les préférences
    savePrefs();

}
```

And when i load back te preferences, i want them to get the same color as chosen in the addButton() method.

I use a LinearView placed into a ScrollView.

**How to check if a button background color is the same as the previous one in the view ?**

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do that (only found a getter for Drawable and one for tint list), but why don't you just keep the last random number in the while loop to compare it to the new random number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way i could think of is to save the random (color) into a list and u could access each button by it's number and check if it has the same color with the previous one.

add `List<int> colors = new ArrayList<int>();` outside the function

and in the function

```
random = new Random().nextInt(lesCouleurs.size());
colors.add(random);
```

then compare the items of the list

if this answer solved the problem please mark it as the correct answer 
thank you

Comment: Thank you for this idea ! i didn't think about it !